# PostgreSQL Native Query: JSON value not storing properly

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql

I have a service that processes user data. We are batch testing against PostgreSQL native query for performance, but are having trouble storing JSON values the way we anticipate. The JSON value is being passed to the native query, but the query is processing and storing the JSON data improperly.

The query is currently storing the JSON data into our PostgreSQL table as such:

```
"{\"user_id\":\"12345\",\"user_name\":\"test_name\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\"}"
```

This is our native query:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO USER_DATA_TEST (USER_DATA) VALUES to_json(:#{#userData.userData})",
        nativeQuery = true)
public void saveUserData(@Param("userData") UserData userData);
```

We would like our data to be stored properly in JSON format, such as:

```
{"user_id": "12345", "user_name": "test_name", "email": "test@test.com"}
```

Comment: 1)  What is the data type for `USER_DATA` in the Postgres table? 2) What is the value of `UserData userData`?

Comment: Yes, but what is the actual value for `userData.userData`?

Comment: The data type for USER_DATA column is JSON and the userData.userData is:

"{"user_id": "12345", "user_name": "test_name", "email": "test@test.com"}"

Comment: The query is invalid to begin with. After the values keyword you need parentheses: `values (...)`. If you pass a String, try `values (cast(:userData as jsonb))`  if the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be) or `cast(... as json)` if the column is defined as `json`

Comment: This solution worked, thank you for your help! It was casting incorrectly. cast(:#{#userData.userData} as json) worked!